# use a variable in tikz pgfplot xtick

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, variable

I was drawing a square function using `pgfplots`. So I defined the period `\T`, the number of periods `\nbT`, the max value `\E`.
I can use those variables in my axis preamble except in `xtick`, how is it?

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\def\E{5} %valeur max à définir
\def\T{2} %période à définir
\def\quartT{0.5} % quart de période à définir pour écrire l'abscisse littérale T/4 car les opérations semblent interdites dans extra x tick ou xstick d'ailleurs
\def\nbT{4} %nombre de période à définir

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis} [
scale=2,
title={Tension $u(t)$},
xlabel={$t$}, ylabel={$u(t)$}, xmin=0, xmax=(\T*\nbT)*1.09, ymin=-1.19*\E, ymax=1.19*\E,
width=190pt,axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
extra x ticks={\quartT},
extra x tick labels={$\frac{T}{4}$},
extra y ticks={-\E,0,\E},
extra y tick labels={$-E$,$0$,$E$},
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1,...,\nbT} {                     % boucle de tracé des barres horizontales
    \draw [blue, thick] (#1*\T,\E) -- (#1*\T+\T/2,\E) ; 
        \draw [blue, thick] (#1*\T+\T/2,-\E) -- (#1*\T+\T,-\E) ;
    } ;

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1,...,\nbT} {                     %boucle de tracé des barres verticales
    \draw [blue, thick] (#1*\T,-\E) -- (#1*\T,\E) ;
        \draw [blue, thick] (#1*\T+\T/2,-\E) -- (#1*\T+\T/2,\E) ;
    } ;

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I Am new here, sorry to see how my code uploaded....

Comment: Select the code and hit Ctrl + K, or click the button marked `{}` above the text field, then it will be marked up properly.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking about though, what exactly do you want to change about your diagram?

Comment: hi, thx for your help. I would like to be able to define "extra x ticks" with a calculated variable like 0.25*\T instead of having to declare an additional variable \quartT. It is weird beacause I can use calculated variables everywhere in my axis preambule but there...I guess this is how it works. Anyway. By the way, I found a better solution using the floor function:

Comment: \addplot[
 blue,
 %thick,
 domain=0:\T*\nbT,
 samples=1000*\T,
 ] {-2*\E*(floor(1-sin(360*x/\T))-0.5) };

Comment: You could use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\quartT}{0.25*\T}` instead of `\def` for `\quartT`.

Comment: apparently the ctrl+K tip only works for the post, not the related comments...Or did I miss something...

Comment: good idea thx, I am starting to use pgfplot ad tikz really, it was my first loop and variable use.

Comment: No, Ctrl + K only works in posts. For comments, use a backtick (`\``) before and after code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\<macroname>}{<calculation>}` to save the result of a calculation to a macro. Hence, you can use `\pgfmathsetmacro\quartT{\T/4}` to define `\quartT`.

While your alternative method to making the plot itself works, it's not very efficient. It takes noticeably longer time to generate the PDF when you use 1000 samples. Another approach might be to plot a similar expression but with samples only at every half period (starting at -T/4), with the plot type `const plot mark mid`. A `const` plot draws horizontal and vertical lines between the plot points, making it useful here.

Because of the choice of samples, there is no need for the `floor` function and various other numbers, the much simpler `\E*(sin(360/\T*x))` is sufficient.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\E{5} %valeur max à définir
\newcommand\T{2} %période à définir
\pgfmathsetmacro\quartT{\T/4} % quart de période à définir pour écrire l'abscisse littérale T/4 car les opérations semblent interdites dans extra x tick ou xstick d'ailleurs
\newcommand\nbT{4} %nombre de période à définir

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis} [
scale=2,
title={Tension $u(t)$},
xlabel={$t$}, ylabel={$u(t)$},
xmin=0, xmax=(\T*\nbT)*1.09, ymin=-1.19*\E, ymax=1.19*\E,
width=190pt,axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
extra x ticks={\quartT},
extra x tick labels={$\frac{T}{4}$},
extra y ticks={-\E,0,\E},
extra y tick labels={$-E$,$0$,$E$},
]

\addplot [blue, thick, samples at={-\quartT,\quartT,...,\T*\nbT}, const plot mark mid] {\E*(sin(360/\T*x))};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thx, clever indeed, this const plot option i didn't know about may be usefull in the future.

Comment: @JeanLallemand I updated my answer, the plotted expression could be simplified a lot.